# Angular: Data callback never stops even when unsubscribe function is used

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to update the data from the api using this function

```
ngOnInit(){
        setInterval(()=>{
            this.getPhonebook();
        }, 1000);
    }



getPhonebook() {
    this.showPhonebook = this.beaconProvider.getPhoneBookDirectories().subscribe(data => {
        this.infos = data;
    }, (err) =>{
        console.log(err);
    })
```

}

and trying to destroy it using this:

```
 ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.showPhonebook.unsubscribe();   
 }

 ngOnDestroy(){
    this.showPhonebook.unsubscribe();   
 }
```

The Problem is when i try to destroy using `ngDestroy` or attach it to `IonViewDidLeave()` lifecycle the function still calls even when I'm already on a different page. So is there a way to achieve the auto update I desire angularly since my concern that given a large transaction the `setInterval` will cause errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use setInterval in your component you will need to set clearInterval.

```
 myInterval: any;

 ngOnInit(){
    this.myInterval = setInterval(()=>{
        this.getPhonebook();
    }, 1000);
}



ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.myInterval);
 }
```

Comment: No problem, spent forever figuring this one out myself a while ago :)