# Angular interpolated value display not updating when changed in timeout

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Angular 6.0.1.

This problem is manifesting itself inside a large application, but I created a simple component to try and see what is going on.  The simple component has a simple template:

`{{myProp}}`

In the ngOnInit, I set `this.myProp = 'hello';` and I see the word **hello** on screen as I would expect.  So far so good.

However, if I now try to update the value of `myProp` in a `setTimeout`, it never updates the UI:

```
this.myProp = 'hello';
setTimeout(() => {
  this.myProp = 'goodbye';
}, 3000);
```

The value shown in the UI is still **hello**.

If I inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in my constructor and call `cdr.detectChanges()` inside the timer, the UI updates.

Is this expected behavior, or what am I doing wrong?  I wouldn't expect to have to call `detectChanges` for this.  I have not changed the `ChangeDetectorStrategy` for the component so it is still `default`.

Note, that in the "real" app, I'm not updating `myProp` in a timer, but inside an `Observable` subscription.  The UI is not updating there and that is what has led me to investigate this and end at the timer as the simplest possible reproduction of the problem.  As near as I can tell, updating the property value in any type of async manner is not showing the change in the UI.

**Update**

I think that my reference to setTimeout confused things.  I was using that as a means of debugging.  Instead of trying to rework this question, I posted a new question here ([Angular interpolated value not updating on subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690866/angular-interpolated-value-not-updating-on-subscription)) with a better explanation and the ngRx code that is causing me grief.

**Update #2**
The problem was caused by a parent component having its `ChangeDetectionStrategy` set to `OnPush`.  See the question I referenced above.

Comment: Updating a property in an async method does update the view. Something else is going on. Please show us the context where `setTimeout` is called. Or make a stackblitz that shows the problem.

Comment: You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3zwx1) that the view is updated when the code in your question is executed. The problem in your project may be caused by a library that redefines `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected action. The javascript method [Window setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is a `Window` command. This means that it is called outside the main `zone.js` thread *(by which I mean the general change detection contained out of box in an Angular application)*, which is the expected plan. If you would like to contain your **setTimeout()** method you need to assign it to a variable contained inside your Angular TypeScript application.

This behavior is the most distinct when using a similar method in the same family of functions called from `window`: [the Window setInterval() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

You are able to contain this, and similar `Window` methods. The **setTimeout()** command needs the `ChangeDetectorRef` attached to it to detect changes in order to *listen to Events Emitted*. You can also insert commands by assigning the executed method to a component variable (similar to this answer on how to stop **setInterval()** after a component is destroyed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363275/angular-data-callback-never-stops-even-when-unsubscribe-function-is-used/45363295#45363295)).

Comment: I thought Angular already monkeypatched setTimeout to make it zone-aware.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter They made it work so that when you use an arrow function it correctly refers to the parent as the referring object, if I'm not mistaken. In general it should still be run on the Window thread by default, but if the parent is a subscription function (as your updated question) then it will continue to be outside your app's zone (in this case, it'll be within an rxjs module's zone). The best route is to avoid needing anything like this, but adding a cdRef in rare-necessary-circumstances won't slow thins down much at all.

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter And stackblitz example to show how w/o arrow it will not update since the parent is run in `Window` zone (and sort of re-affirm you that I do know what I'm talking about ;D): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-djwgom