# Angular interpolated value not updating on subscription

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-changedetection

- Angular 6.0.1
- ngRx 6.0.1

I have an interpolated value set up in my View:

`{{firstName}}`

It is not updating when the value of the field it is bound to changes.  The value **is** changing though - if I log it out to the console inside the subscription, I see the updated value.  It just doesn't update in the UI.

Here's the relevant code:

Subscription from my component:

```
private subscribeToCurrentPerson(): void {
    this.tState$ = this.store
      .pipe(select(selectors.getCurrentPerson), takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
      .subscribe((cp: Person) => {
        if (cp) {
          const name: string = cp.primaryName.value.parsedValue.givenNames[0];
          this.firstName = name;
          console.log('name: ' + name);  // <-- this shows correct new value
        }
  });
}
```

`subscribeToCurrentPerson` is called from the component's ngOnInit. Prior to this, the `firstName` property is undefined.

The `selectors.getCurrentPerson` selector looks like this:

```
export const getCurrentPerson: MemoizedSelector<{}, Person> = 
    createSelector(getTState, (tState: ITState) => {
      console.log('selector: ', tState); // <-- this logs the correct new value
      return tState ? tState.currentPerson : null;
    });
```

The `currentPerson` value returned from the selector is a newly created object.  This is happening on the first run of the application, so prior to this `tState` is undefined.

If I inject `ChangeDetectorRef` in my constructor and call `cdr.detectChanges()` inside the subscription, the UI updates.  But it seems to me I don't typically need to use `ChangeDetectorRef` like this, that it should "just work".

I think the problem is my deeply nested property (`cp.primaryName.value.parsedValue.givenNames`).  I inherited these entities from a non-ngRx project, but I think my next step is to try flattening that structure to see if that makes ngRx and the Angular change detector happier.

Is there something else I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

I've take the deeply nested property out of the picture by simply updating a local property on my component inside the subscription.  So the `subscribeToCurrentPerson` function now looks like this:

```
private subscribeToCurrentPerson(): void {
        this.tState$ = this.store
          .pipe(select(selectors.getCurrentPerson), takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
          .subscribe((cp: Person) => {
            this.myProp = 'goodbye';
            this['newProp'] = 'world';
      });
    }
```

`myProp` is an existing property on my component I added for testing.
`newProp` does not exist until it is added via the bracket notation inside the subscription.  Here's the results:

- `myProp` is not updated - it shows the value I assigned it when it was declared.  However, if I do not assign a value when the property is declared, then the value assigned in the subscription is shown in the UI properly.
- `newProp` **is** shown in the UI correctly

I am now completely baffled.  **It seems like once a property has a value it is never updated in the UI**, even if the value itself does change (which I can tell by logging to the console after updating the value).

I'm not explicitly setting the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` for the component, so it is `Default`.

Everything works if I call `detectChanges`, but I don't think that should be necessary.

Comment: Since commenting on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51682170/1009922) and showing in a stackblitz that the view should update automatically... I am facing the same problem as you in my own code.

Comment: whats your change detection strategy? Default or onPush?

Comment: I've tried each, but currently Default.

Comment: Sounds like you're right, as far as the deeply nested properties go. There's nothing that sticks out about the code being outside zone besides the reassignments/nested properties inside the constructor. JS naturally disagrees with heavily nested objects and sub-reassignments after all. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, maybe someone else will see something I don't!

Comment: NP, thanks @Z.Bagley.  I've taken the deeply nested properties out of the picture and am now utterly baffled as to what is going on (see my Update, above).  Something is stopping the UI from updating once a property has a value, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Check parent components for any `OnPush` change detection

Comment: And we have a winner!  @Dummy, your handle is a misnomer!  If you put that in as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a parent component has its change detection strategy set to `OnPush` then this parent's tree of components will not be checked by angular's change detection mechanism, although this parent and its children's `ngOnChanges` method is still being called every time any `@Input` properties change. To let angular know that some component in this tree needs to update, inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` into that component and use its API to notify angular about the update, e.g `detectChanges` or `markForCheck`

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times data updates from component will not reflect the HTML template. In such a case, you can use interpolation with ternary operators.

```
{{firstName ? firstName : ''}}
```